# vb.net button click event not firing first time

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button, onclick

I have a very simple Textbox and Button, but Button click event not firing at first time ( only firing in second click)

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtSurvey" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <br />
<asp:Button  ID="BtnGoSurvey" runat="server" Text="LetsGo"/>
```

The code is very simple too

```
 Protected Sub BtnGoSurvey_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnGoSurvey.Click
        Session("IDSurvey") = TxtSurvey.Text
        BtnGoSurvey.PostBackUrl = "~/Survey.aspx"
End Sub
```

What i'm doing wrong ?
Thanks for help

Comment: You wanna move to ~/Survey.aspx on first click ?

Comment: Yes, but first of all, i wanna write in Session the input text in TextBox(TxtSurvey)
I can use server.Transfer, but i'm not shure if Server.Transfer do a postback.

Thanks for reply !

Comment: Okay, but any specific reason for not using Response.Redirect ?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Response.Redirect, then following is supposed to work:

```
Protected Sub BtnGoSurvey_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnGoSurvey.Click
    Session("IDSurvey") = TxtSurvey.Text
    Response.Redirect("~/Survey.aspx",True)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot, Shami.
That's just that i need !!!!

Thank you one more time 
Best regards:

Comment: Glad to help you, accept this as answer it this is the case!